# MYSQL GROUP BY Query results seem limited to 31

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a Raspberry Pi temperature monitoring system setup and all is running fine except I now noticed that my Daily Min, Max and AVG query do not show more then 31 results. The problem seems to be with the GROUP BY statement and when I limit the amount of days to anything less then 31 I get all the latest data, but anything more then it will only show the 31 oldest days of data.  I have a chart that is supposed to show every days MIN, MAX and AVG temperature.

Please if somebody can help me.

With this it will only show me data from the 26/05/2014 (first day of my logging) till 27/06/2014 and stop there:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d') AS date2, 
   MAX(temperature), 
   MAX(temp2), MIN(temperature), 
   MIN(temp2), AVG(temperature), AVG(temp2) 
FROM data
GROUP BY date2
ORDER BY id ASC
```

With this it will show the last 31 Days of data (from today minus 30 days) - not what I want:

```
mysql_select_db("mysensors", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%W %e %b %Y') AS date,
                              MAX(temperature), 
                              MAX(temp2), MIN(temperature), MIN(temp2),
                              AVG(temperature), AVG(temp2) 
                FROM data
                WHERE DATE(`date`) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
                GROUP BY DAY(date)
                ORDER BY id ASC") or die ("Imposible");
```

Comment: You are grouping the results by day, which is why you are seeing only 31 results.

There are only 31 unique days (01-31).

Comment: @Alwin Why not make that an answer? That's freaking brilliant!

Comment: Use something as simple as **`GROUP BY DATE(date)`** to get a row for each distinct "date" (yyyy-mm-dd) value. There are other expressions you can use in the GROUP BY clause to get an equivalent result e.g. `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d')`.  (This is a comment, and not an answer, because it's not clear what question you were actually asking.)

Comment: @spencer7593 - Thank you - That worked!  Sorry, I am a total noob and only started with PHP, MySQL and Python a month ago an busy learning a lot! Thank to all. This site is the best!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are grouping the results by day, which is why you are seeing only 31 results.

There are only 31 unique days (01-31).

Comment: Unbelievable. Spotting something like that.

Comment: You guys are like Ninjas! Took a minute after I asked the question for you to tell me my mistake :-)  Thanks.  A pointer to how I can group it differently like Day of Year ?

Comment: As suggested by spencer7593, you could use `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d')` to group by date.